# Making $1 uppercase in substitution

Tags: regex, substitution, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to move our web-based help files from an existing IIS server onto an instance of Tomcat, because we need TomCat for a specific application. I know I could probably plug tomcat into IIS, but I don't want to because a) I want to learn tomcat and b) I prefer less overhead and less software, rather than more.

The issue I have now is that our help files are available in multiple language, mainly in English, so the URL includes that language, for instance: http://help.mydomain.com/EN/product-help/ . However, some links to the help files (some of which I can't control) are in lowercase, meaning the request I'm getting is http://help.mydomain.com/en/product-help/ . My first thought was to make everything case insensitive but it's clear in the Apache Tomcat documentation that this MUST NOT be done on Windows systems, so I have to find an alternative.

Because I already have urlrewrite on the system for other reasons, I figured, why not just try to do it with a little regex? Doesn't seem to be so simple though... I have 7 languages so my starting match is `<from>/(en|fr|de|csh|es|it|jp|pt)/(.*?)</from>` , and I'd like for the result to be something like `<to>/uc($1)/$2</to>`

I've tried looking this up on google, trust me, but every solution I've found isn't working with the url rewrite filter. I've tried the following:

```
<from>/(en|fr|de|csh|es|it|jp|pt)/(.*?)</from>
<to>/uc($1)/$2</to>

<from>/uc(en|fr|de|csh|es|it|jp|pt)/(.*?)</from>
<to>/$1/$2</to>

<from>/(en|fr|de|csh|es|it|jp|pt)/(.*?)</from>
<to>/\U$1/$2</to>

<from>/(en|fr|de|csh|es|it|jp|pt)/(.*?)</from>
<to>/${upper:$1}/$2</to>
```

None of those work (the last one, ${upper:$1} is a function mentionned in the urlrewrite documentation, maybe it's just unclear how it should be used with a backreference)

Comment: I assume that you don't want to simply use one rule per language?

Comment: Yes, I would like to avoid having one rule per language. Plus, what if someone does a "En" link? And what if there are other similar situations where I need to do this for various combinations, like fixing Index, INDEX, etc? It's something that's "good to know" in any case.

Comment: You could write a rewrite config generator. :D

Comment: You could write a program that takes a compact pattern and expands it into many similar configuration directives. E.g. transform `<from>/{{{en|fr|de|csh|es|it|jp|pt}}}/(.*?)</from><to>/{{{upper:$1}}}/$1</to>` to many rules like `<from>/en/(.*?)</from><to>/EN/$1</to>` :D

Yes, I'm mostly joking.

Comment: thank you for that bit of humor, thejh :)
But no, that's not really what I want to do :P